# Numpy equivalent of a[i] for i in indices

Tags: python, numpy

What is a way to use NumPy to create a new list that consists of a desired subset of the elements of another list?

```
indices = [0,2,1,1]
a = [8,7,6,5,4]
b = [a[i] for i in indices] # returns [8,6,7,7]
```

I'm looking for a single function, if possible.  Something like this:

```
import numpy as np
indices = np.array([0,2,1,1])
a = np.array([8,7,6,5,4])
b = np.get_selected_elements(a, indices)
```

Comment: Use `b = a[indices]`

Comment: @eyllanesc Ah, that does work, but not for multidimensional arrays (or at least it does not work as expected).  I was hoping for something that could be scaled to multidimensional arrays (although not stated).  I will edit the question.

Comment: multidimensional arrays: `b = a[indicesx, indicesy]`

Comment: Do not modify this question, your question is duplicated and the example that shows shows it. Create a new question, but before that check if it has not been asked before and we will mark it to close again if so and probably also downvotes.